# jQuery - Rotate image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-rotate

I tried to create image rotate but it's not working. I tried different codes from different sites but don't know what's wrong.

This is my code.

```js
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({ 
  bind: 
  { 
    click: function(){
      value +=90;
      $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
    }
  } 
});
```

```css
#image{
  margin:200px 200px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sobekrepository.org/includes/jquery-rotate/2.2/jquery-rotate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://jqueryrotate.com/images/chrome_32x32.png" id="image" onclick="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `jQuery` is not defined, check this code:

```js
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({
  bind: {
    click: function() {
      value += 90;
      $(this).rotate({
        animateTo: value
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#image {
  margin: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/apple_416x416.jpg" id="image" onclick="" />
```

Comment: Your code snippet is working properly on the site but its not working in my code..